# FastAPI: where to set exclude_unset=True?

Tags: patch, fastapi

I am learning fastAPI and don't know how to update user info partially. The given solution is to set exclude_unset=True, but I don't know where to write it. Here are my pieces of code:

routers/user.py:

```
@router.patch('/{id}', status_code=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
def update_user(id, request: sUser, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    user = db.query(mUser).filter(mUser.id == id)

    if not user.first():
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail=f'The User with the id {id} is not found')

    user.update(request.dict(exclude={'createdAt'}, exclude_unset=True))

    db.commit()

    return user.first()
```

PS exclude = {'createdAt'} works, but exclude_unset=True doesn't..

Here is my user schema:

schemas.py

```
class User(BaseModel):
    username: str
    dob: datetime.date
    password: str
    createdAt: datetime.datetime
```

Answer (score 3):

that's because you are using it on a `User` model instance.

If you want to receive partial updates, it's very useful to use the parameter `exclude_unset` in **Pydantic**'s model's `.dict()`.

so use it on **Pydantic** object.

more info in documentation: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#modeldict

Answer (score 0):

Set it as follows:

```
a.dict(exclude_unset=True)
```

where `a` is the object, see the example here:

https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/1399

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure when it was added, but you can set it on the api decorator. It works by passing this through to `model_dump` when responding.

```py
@app.get("/items/{item_id}"
    , response_model=Item
    , response_model_exclude_unset=True
)
async def read_item(item_id: str):
    return items[item_id]
```

> You can also use:

```py
response_model_exclude_defaults=True
response_model_exclude_none=True
```

https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/#use-the-response_model_exclude_unset-parameter